# how to make html inactive and show loading gif

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css, ajax

I have a modal which pops up when you hit sign up button.

after input, one hits "sign up" button and what i want at this point is to make the actual popup's html content inactive and show in the middle loading gif icon till i will get ajax response.

e.g. code:

```
<div class="modal" id="mymodal">
  <div id="modalcontent">
   <div id="modalhead"> </div>
   <div id="modalbody"> </div>
   <div id="modalfooter"> </div>
  </div>
</div>
```

js:

```
$('#modalcontent').html('<img src=\'/static/img/modalloader.gif\'/>');
```

but it is not setting background html elements inactive, it is removing all the content and big modal is becoming just small as size of loading gif icon..

how can i do this?

Comment: add a modal bg div with absolute position and as big as window; put this on top of content, and then the modal - with bigger z-index.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I ran into a lot of browser issues (especially mobile browsers) with puting a modal with absolute position on the content, so what I do is set up a content container and a waiting gif container

```
<div id='content'>
  <!-- whatever you want to show on your site -->
</div>
<div id='loading' class='hidden'>
  <div class="modal" id="mymodal">
    <div id="modalcontent">
      <div id="modalhead"> </div>
      <div id="modalbody"> </div>
      <div id="modalfooter"> </div>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```

---

In css

```
.hidden{display: none !important;}
```

---

And js:

```
//onlaoad function yadayadayada {

  // (...whatever way you trigger the request...)
  showLoading();
  $.ajax(url: //Idontknow,
         success: //handle it here or in complete,
         error: //handle it here or in complete,
         complete: function(){
           hideLoading();
         });

  // some more whatever

// end of onload function }

function showLoading(){
  $('#content').addClass('hidden');
  $('#loading').removeClass('hidden');
}

function hideLoading(){
  $('#content').removeClass('hidden');
  $('#loading').addClass('hidden');
}
```

It seems a little weird to do all the hide and show, but since I have been struggling with browsers that handle absolute positioned elements in a different way any sane person would expect, I found this to be the easiest and most straight forward way to avoid running into issues.

Answer (score 0):

You can use ajaxStart method to show the loader.

E.g from the Jquery Website:

```
$( document ).ajaxStart(function() {
  $( "#loading" ).show();
});
```